# Endpoint services with url alias name

Tags: views, 7, services

Is it possible the to view xml/json format data with url alias name instead of endpoint_path/node/1 or endpoint_path/node/2

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Services node resource extension](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_node_resource_extension) module

> Extends functionality for the node resource available through services module.
>
> Additional Resources:
>
> -lookup - provides a resource to request a node through the url alias.
>
> -POST data = [ 'alias' => the url alias. ]

Comment: Thanx for quick reply Mohan.  previously i used this url( like base_url/node/9) to get json format data after configured this module gave url(base_url/custom_name.htm like) . It show empty page. Can you please help me with a suggetion.